# iOS (Swift) - Casting root view controller of the app delegate's window works in simulator, but fails when app is loaded on phone

Tags: ios, swift, uikit

When I run my app with the following lines of code (inside the AppDelegate.swift file):

```
func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager!,
    didRangeBeacons beacons: [AnyObject],
    inRegion region: CLBeaconRegion!) {

    let viewController:ViewController = window!.rootViewController as! ViewController
    viewController.beacons = beacons as! [CLBeacon]
    viewController.tableView.reloadData()

 ...... }
```

it only runs flawlessly when I run the app in the simulator. Otherwise, when I run the app on my phone I get this runtime error:

> Could not cast value of type 'UITableViewController' (0x198be57d0) to
>   'beaconTest.ViewController' (0x1000e15d0).

ViewController is subclass of UITableViewController defined like so:

http://wwww.pastebin.com/1bM80ipp

Comment: When you say it runs flawlessly in the simulator, are you sure this code is getting executed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Where is the window's root view controller being set?

If it is in a storyboard, ensure that the class of the root view controller is `ViewController` and not `UITableViewController`.